# prevent camera from working based on geo location(iOS, Android)

Tags: ios, iphone, security, camera, microphone

Is it possible prevent camera or microphone of iPhone/Android from working based on the location of the device?

I want to make the functionality of camera or microphone disable  in the certain area.

Is it possible in iOS or Android?

Are there SDKs, solutions or libraries?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't be done for iOS - at least not for an app available in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

For Android you can use the Device Administration API to lock all cameres of the device. The camera (and flash) will be disabled for the user and for all the apps. Regarding the geo location you should retrieve the device location (Network/GPS) and switch between lock/unlock according to it.

For ios it is possible to disable the camera app via a Mobile Device Management (MDM) for Enterprise deployment.

I don't know if it is possible to do it dynamically based on the device location. I will appreciate if someone will response to this qestion too.

Answer (score 0):

As @rmaddy says, you can't do this for iOS, unless you are targeting jailbroken devices. And on a jailbroken device all bets are off, since the user has root access to bypass your restrictions.

As a matter of policy Apple does not allow third party apps to alter the base functions of the device. Apps run in "user space" in a restrictive "app sandbox" and can only modify themselves.